# How to create relations between Okta users and local database tables?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, okta

I have a spring boot application with a MySQL database which is designed to store information about doctor appointments. [image]

Let's say that I have an endpoint at `localhost:8080/visit/{id}` which is secured as such that only authenticated users with group claims of patient and doctor can access it.

How can I integrate an okta user who is a doctor or a patient, which I use to log in with with this database table relationship?

I thought of storing the user data in a local table on login based on the user claims, but it duplicates the users stored in okta which seems pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not a bad idea to store the user data in a local table on login based on the user claims since you might need to correlate some other info for this user, which might not be convenient to use Okta user only.

Comment: Possibly, however for now I'm going to try to have a table for users with: id, okta userid and relations mapped with annotation (@OneToMany). Will report findings later.